# React Timer using seState and Interval not Working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, state

I have a timer MM:SS that is counting upwards to a set time of MM:SS. i.e. from 00:00 to 45:00.

My state is current set at.

```
  const [currentTime, setCurrentTime] = useState<CurrentTime>({
    minutes: 0,
    seconds: 58,
  });
```

My useEffect timer to continiously update time is set up as...

```
 useEffect(() => {
  let interval: any;

  if (!finished) {
  interval = setInterval(() => {
    if (currentTime.seconds === 60) {
      setCurrentTime({
        ...currentTime,
        minutes: currentTime.minutes++,
        seconds: 0,
      });
    } else {
      setCurrentTime({
        ...currentTime,
        minutes: currentTime.minutes,
        seconds: currentTime.seconds++,
      });
    }

   }, 1000);
    } else {
      clearInterval(interval);
    }

    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, [finished]);
```

The problem I have is that when the seconds reach 60. The minute property updates, but the seconds property never updates and is always stuck at 60, leading to a continuous output of 01:00, 02:00, 03:00, 04:00 05:00, ..., in the console.

What do I need to do so that when 60 seconds is reached, the minute goes up by 1 and the seconds goes back to 0 at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are mutating state and have an issue with stale enclosure. Use a functional state update to correctly update from the previous state. Move the conditional check on `currentTime.seconds` ***into*** the functional update. You will also want to check and "reset" the seconds to 0 when 59 seconds is reached so that on the next "tick" it is 0 instead of reaching 60.

```
useEffect(() => {
  let interval;

  if (!finished) {
    interval = setInterval(() => {
      setCurrentTime((currentTime) => {
        if (currentTime.seconds === 59) {
          return {
            ...currentTime,
            minutes: currentTime.minutes + 1,
            seconds: 0
          };
        } else {
          return {
            ...currentTime,
            minutes: currentTime.minutes,
            seconds: currentTime.seconds + 1
          };
        }
      });
    }, 1000);
  } else {
    clearInterval(interval);
  }

  return () => clearInterval(interval);
}, [finished]);
```

[image: Edit react-timer-using-sestate-and-interval-not-working]

Comment: Thank you for the response! I managed to get it working by adding a reference to the previous state when attempting to change the state, just like you said,  AND adding currentTime as a dependency in the useEffect dependency array.